# Angular material select and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im trying to get multiselect by placing checkbox inside select option.
if this is my html code...

```html
<md-input-container>
  <md-select ng-model="clients.regions" placeholder="Select a regions">
    <md-option ng-repeat="data in regions">
      <md-checkbox  ng-model="clients.regions">
         {{ data }}
    </md-checkbox>
  </md-option>
</md-select>
</md-input-container>

      <pre>selected: {{clients.regions}}</pre>
```

from controller im getting regions ...

```js
  $http.get('/api/v1/secure/lov/regions').success(function(response) {
    $scope.regions=response.values;
  });
```

Regions is an array ... i got no idea how to store and edit with select options with checkbox inside ...

```js
    regions : [{ type: String, trim: true, required: true }],
```

If there is any easy way ...Do help ..*thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen what you describe, it is probably impossible. The regular way to do it is to have tags added thanks to an autocomplete input text. You can build your own with [datalist](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#datalist), or use this [angular-tagger](https://github.com/monterail/angular-tagger) project